# JDK 15 Sealed Classes - how to use across packages?

Tags: java, sealed-class, java-15, java-sealed-type

I have a simple sealed class, `MyShape`:

```
public sealed class MyShape permits MyCircle {

    private final int width;
    private final int height;

    public MyShape(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int width() {
        return width;
    }

    public int height() {
        return height;
    }
}
```

And one simple subclass, `MyCircle`:

```
public final class MyCircle extends MyShape {

    public MyCircle(int width) {
        super(width, width);
    }
}
```

Everything compiles and works when both classes are in the same package. If I move MyCircle into a sub-package, then the build breaks with: `java: class is not allowed to extend sealed class: org.example.MyShape`.

My understanding from the [JDK 15 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/language/sealed-classes-and-interfaces.html) is that this should work. Am I missing a step?

I've [created a GitHub repo](https://github.com/terheyden/SealedClasses/tree/master/src/main/java/org/example) if you want to experiment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the documentation that you have linked:

[JDK 15 Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/language/sealed-classes-and-interfaces.html)

> They must be in the same module as the sealed class (if the sealed class is in a named module) or **in the same package (if the sealed class is in the unnamed module)**.

Comment: Thanks but I think you've bolded the wrong portion of the text. If I had not been using the unnamed module, then having `MyCircle` in a different package would have worked as expected. If the question is "how to use across packages" then the answer is "don't use the unnamed module."